# C program only in two loops

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I want to write C program having following output. There is a condition. It should be done with maximum two loops only.

```
Output
           *
          * *
         * * *
        * * * *
       * * * * *
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I can do it with one loop, or even zer0 – seriously, the quality of your question is ....

Comment: show us what you tried.

Comment: I have done it but in three loops. I need it in two loops.

Comment: @ShuklaJay...Post your code...It is homework...

Comment: Post your 3 loop code and then people here can help you reduce it to 2 loops.

Comment: @ShuklaJay Why loop three are necessary?

Comment: Any help would be appreciated ? Well, [look at this](http://www.amazon.com/C-Programming-Language-2nd-Edition/dp/0131103628)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a code without any loop.

```
int main() {
    printf("    *\n");
    printf("   * *\n");
    printf("  * * *\n");
    printf(" * * * *\n");
    printf("* * * * *\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be made: If you're thinking that you need one loop to make the left margin.

```
    int n = 5;
    int bias = 7;
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
        printf("%*s", bias + n - i, "");
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

here after how to display it in 2 for loops

```
int main()
{
    int n=5; //number of lines
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("%*c", (n-i), '*');
        for(j=0; j<i; j++)
            printf("%s", " *");
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```